# How to make available libpng to packge ImageMagick in julia?

Tags: imagemagick, julia, libpng

While running `build ImageMagick` on CentOS7, getting error:

```
LoadError: LibraryProduct(nothing, ["libpng16"], :libpng, 
"Prefix(/opt/julia/julia-1.10/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/ImageMagick/deps/usr)")
is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl
```

It has been observed that `libpng.v1.6.31.x86_64-linux-gnu.tr.gz` has been downloaded and unzipped to `/opt/julia/julia-1.10/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/ImageMagick/deps/usr` folder by the build script.

Please guide me in resolving the isue!

Comment: If all you did was unzip it, that is not enough. You need to install it where ImageMagick can find it and then reinstall imagemagick. See https://imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php. Sorry, I am not a Linux user and so cannot give more advice.

Comment: Thanks Mr.fmw42! I am new to both Julia and ImageMagick! I have to verify whether the imagemagick referred by you and the julia package, ImageMagick referred by me are same or different! More over it is built by the build script of the ImageMagick package!

Comment: Perhaps you need to discuss this with the Julia developers.

Comment: Executing ...deps/build.jl, downloads, extracts and generates deps.jl for the following: a)Zlib.v1.2.11 b)libpng.v1.6.31 c)libjpeg.v9.0.0-b d)libtiff.v4.0.9 e)ImageMagick.v6.9.10-12 and then downloading and executing build_ImageMagick.v6.9.10-12.jl resolves the issue!